# fetch data from postgres and replace values of column depending on multiple condition

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I fetch column of postgres table and now i want to replace values of  column 'B' depending on  column 'A' .if it is greater then a certain number then replace value of 'B'... I am trying to write the code but i can not understand how i will execute if statements...I also tried to do this with panda but i can not make a logic there as well. Any help will be appreciated

```html
import psycopg2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
connection=psycopg2.connect(user="user",database="db",password="****",host= "localhost")
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from mytable")
col_clean=cursor.fetchall()
for row in  col_clean:
     if "a" == 10 :
        'b'.replace(0.000,(9/100))
    elif "a" ==20:
        'b'.replace(0.000,(22/100))
    elif "a" == 30:
        'b'.replace(0.000,(70/100))
    elif "a" == 40:
        'b'.replace(0.000, (80 / 1000))
     ELSE
        'b.replace(0.000, (100 / 100))
cursor.execute('Insert into mytable("b") VALUES(%s)',%row)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: You want to insert a new row instead of updating the existing row?

Comment: no, i want to update the existing rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just update the rows in place instead of iterating through them.

```
import psycopg2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
connection=psycopg2.connect(user="user",database="db",password="****",host= "localhost")
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""UPDATE mytable set b = 
CASE a 
  WHEN '10' THEN 0.09
  WHEN '20' THEN 0.22
  WHEN '30' THEN 0.70
  WHEN '40' THEN 0.80
  ELSE 1
END""")
connection.commit()
```

Edit: fixed for "a" being text.

Comment: it is throwing following error :  HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Actually  my 'a' column is text and I am assigning integer.... Is there any way to fix it

Comment: I updated the answer to use text comparison.  If you are actually storing integers in a, it would be better to use that data type.

Comment: now it is only updating value of ELSE. i mean in all columns there is 1 and if I skip ELSE it update as null

Comment: I construst a new table where i specify column A type as bigint and it work fine. but when I apply it on original table whose column value is text  then it just apply Else value

Comment: Are there any values in a that equal 10, 20, 30, or 40?  It would help a lot if you would include your table definition and some data.  Without those, I have to guess.

Comment: yes in column A there are values like 50,100,200  all are integers but column type is text because i converted 1 xml file into postgres table. and in column b all values are 0.00

Comment: Ok, but 50, 100, and 200 would all fall under the else clause.